# PowerDNS: multiple supermasters and transfering domain

Tags: bind, powerdns

I've got a setup with multiple supermasters (bind) and multiple superslaves (pdns). It all seems to work just fine, pdns is being updated when I'm adding or changing a domain. But, when I want to migrate a domain from one master to another, pdns doesn't like it. It tells me the new server isn't a master for this domain, although I deleted the domain on the old server.

Now, I think that part of the problem is, that pdns doesn't get an update when a domain is deleted, which would also explain a lot of dead domains in my pdns. It looks like the slave is constantly polling a server and getting RCODE=5 back. The master isn't aware of the domain and the slave thinks the master still serves that domain.

Anyone familiar with this problem?

Comment: Hmm, ok, seems like design. A slave wont delete a domain. It looks like I have to do it myself.